# Example where letrec/letrec* is better than let with internal defines or named let ?

Tags: scheme

The two examples Kent Dybvig gives in The Scheme Programming Language for letrec and letrec* are:

```
(letrec ([sum (lambda (x)
             (if (zero? x)
                 0
                 (+ x (sum (- x 1)))))])
   (sum 5))
```

and

```
(letrec* ([sum (lambda (x)
            (if (zero? x)
                    0
                (+ x (sum (- x 1)))))]
         [f (lambda () (cons n n-sum))]
         [n 15]
         [n-sum (sum n)])
  (f))
```

The first can also be written as a named let:

```
(let sum ([x 5]) 
  ((lambda (x)
                 (if (zero? x)
                     0
                     (+ x (sum (- x 1))))) x))
```

and the second can be written as a let with internal defines:

```
(let ()
  (define sum  (lambda (x)
               (if (zero? x)
               0 
                   (+ x (sum (- x 1))))))
  (define f (lambda () (cons n n-sum)))
  (define n 15)
  (define n-sum (sum n))
  (f))
```

The letrec/letrec* forms don't seem any more concise or clearer than the named let or let with internal defines forms.

Can someone show me an example where letrec/letrec* does improve the code or is necessary instead of named let or let with internal defines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the first example can be rewritten using a named `let`, but note that there is no need for the `lambda` form in there:

```
(let sum ([x 5])
  (if (zero? x)
    0
    (+ x (sum (- x 1)))))
```

This kind of transformation is a bit misleading -- it is fine to do in case you're defining a single "looping function" (in the broad not-only-tail-recursive sense) and immediately use it on a known input.  But usually, when you see examples such as the one you gave, the intention is to show the definition and use of a local function, so it's possible to do this transformation only because it's a for-demonstration toy example.

Secondly, note that a named `let` is usually **not** a primitive form -- the implementation strategy that practically all Scheme implementations use is to have that form expand into a `letrec`.  It is therefore still a good idea to understand `letrec` if you want to understand named-`let`s.  (And this is a fundamental feature: being able to do self-reference via a recursive scope.)

Finally, the example that you gave with internal definitions is similar to named-`let`s: it is a syntactic sugar that expands into a `letrec` (which can be either a proper `letrec` or a `letrec*` with R5RS, and required to be a `letrec*` in R6RS).  So in order to understand how it works, you need to understand `letrec`.  Note also that some implementation that use strict `letrec` would also barf at your second example, and complain that `sum` is undefined.  It is this syntactic sugaring that is behind the main argument for the `letrec*` semantics that was adopted in R6RS: many people like using internal definitions, but then there is a problem that toplevel definitions allow using previous definitions but internal definitions are less convenient in an unexpected way.  With `letrec*`, internal definitions work like toplevel ones.  (More precisely, they work like toplevel barring re-definitions, which means that they're actually like module-toplevel definitions.)

(Note also that (a) both Racket and Chez extend internal bodies to allow definitions and expressions to be mixed which means that the expansion is as straightforward.)

Comment: Are you ever fast Eli :-) And thank you for your amazingly clear explanations.

Comment: One more question Eli. You said that named let is not a primitive form but is usually implemented as a letrec.  Is letrec usually a primitive form or is it us usually implemented as a let with set!'s?  Similarly is let a primitive form or is it usually implemented as a lambda.  Thanks.

Comment: @HarrySpier: `letrec` is usually primitive, though it often does something similar to a `let` and `set!`s.  (It's something that almost never matters, but can be exposed using continuations.)  As for `let` I think that there's much less agreement, with some implementations using `lambda` as the expansion and some treating it as primitive.

Answer (score 2):

I second Eli's answer; named `let` and internal `define` are defined in terms of `letrec`.

I will add some empirical, numerical anecdata to this, though.  I work at a company that uses Scheme.  We have 981 Scheme code files, that sum up to a grand total of 206,878 lines (counting comments, blank lines, the whole thing).  This was written by a team that ranged between 8-16 people over some 8 years.

So, how many uses of `letrec` are in that codebase?  16.  This is compared to about an estimated 7,000 uses of `let` and `let*` (estimated because I'm not gonna bother to refine the regexp I used).  It also looks like all of the `letrec` uses were written by the same guy.

So, I'm not going to be surprised that you won't find much practical use for `letrec`.

Comment: This may just be a testament to the well-designed libraries you're using. All your invocations of `letrec` are really taking place under the guise of `map` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

From some of Kent's students, I have learned the following: `letrec` is implemented in terms of `let` using macro expansion. It expands the `letrec` into a `let` that uses `set!` inside. So your first example would expand to this:

```
(let
  ([sum (void)])
  (set! sum (lambda (x) (if (zero? x) 0 (+ x (sum (- x 1))))))
  (sum 5))
```

Your second, similarly (note that the nested `let`s are a result of the `let*` - also, this may not be a completely correct expansion, but is my best guess):

```
(let
  ([sum (void)] 
  (set! sum (lambda (x) (if (zero? x) 0 (+ x (sum (- x 1))))))
  (let
    [f (void)] 
    (set! f (lambda () (cons n n-sum)))
    (let 
      [n (void)]
      (set! n 15)
      (let
        [n-sum (void)])
        (set! n-sum (sum n))
        (f))
```

I am not 600% sure how the named `let` expands, but Eli suggests that it would be implemented in terms of `letrec` itself (which makes sense and should be pretty obvious). So your named `let` moves from a named `let` into a `letrec` into an unnamed `let`. And your rewrite of the second looks almost exactly like the expansion of it anyway.

If you are interpreting it and looking for good performance, I would lean toward the `letrec` because it is one shorter macro-expand step. Also, `let` gets turned into a lambda so you're using `define`s in your second example instead of `set!`s (which may be heavier).

Of course, if you're compiling, it will probably all fall out in the compiler anyway so just use whichever you think looks nicer (I'm partial to `letrec` because `let` loops remind me of imperative programming but ymmv). That said, it should be up to you, stylistically (since they are more or less equivalent).

That said, let me provide you an example that you may find worthwhile:

```
(letrec
 ([even? (lambda (n) (if (zero? n) #t (odd? (- n 1))))]
  [odd? (lambda (n) (if (zero? n) #f (even? (- n 1))))])
  (even? 88))
```

Using your internal `define` style will yield:

```
(let ()
  (define even? (lambda (n) (if (zero? n) #t (odd? (- n 1)))))
  (define odd? (lambda (n) (if (zero? n) #f (even? (- n 1)))))
  (even? 88))
```

So here the `letrec` code is actually shorter. And, honestly, if you're doing to do something like the latter, why not settle for `begin`?

```
(begin
  (define even? (lambda (n) (if (zero? n) #t (odd? (- n 1)))))
  (define odd? (lambda (n) (if (zero? n) #f (even? (- n 1)))))
  (even? 88))
```

I suspect that `begin` is more of a built-in and, as such, will not get macro-expanded (like `let` will). Finally, [a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060744/scheme-what-are-the-benefits-of-letrec) has been raised on the Lisp stack overflow a bit ago with more or less the same point.